# No magento admin section

Tags: php, magento

I am in the process of setting up magento and as such I am totally new to it, thus all my work is in a test windows environment.

Yesterday after logging into the admin section I was advised to update to 1.8.1 which I did.  After this completed I have no longer been able to access the admin section at all.

I have set php.ini to show all errors but nothing is being shown.

Does anybody have any ideas on what I need to do to fix this issue?

Many thanks in advance.
Graham

Comment: Are you getting admin login screen?

Comment: no nothing at all.  I did get an error message yesterday which said Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php but even this isn't showing now.

Comment: did you tried accessing admin with and without index.php both?

Comment: ok going to just /admin gives nothing but going to /admin/index.php sends me to the frontend home page????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially this was the error message I was getting yesterday:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php

and doing a little research yesterday showed this was something to do with the admin template.

Today I downloaded and ran windiff.exe and did a comparison between the test magento installation and a fresh download of 1.8.1.

Windiff showed that a majority of template files were missing from the test environment.  I copied these across from the fresh install and presto it has come back.

Thanks to @Afroz Alam for looking at this for me.

Cheers
Graham